# How to stop a background service in android?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I tried developing an Android app for SMS Scheduling using AlarmManager and a Background Service.Here is the code snippet:(after getting user input)

```
Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras() ;
        String s1,s2,s3,s4 ;

        s1=b.getString("time") ;
        s2=b.getString("target") ;
        s3=b.getString("text") ;
        s4=b.getString("date") ;
        t1.setText(s1) ;
        t2.setText(s2) ;
        t3.setText(s3) ;
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance() ;
        Intent intent=new Intent(SecondActivity.this,SmsSrevice.class) ;
        intent.putExtra("date",s4) ;
        intent.putExtra("time",s1) ;
        intent.putExtra("num",s2) ;
        intent.putExtra("message",s3) ;
        this.startService(intent);
        PendingIntent pindent=PendingIntent.getService(SecondActivity.this,0, intent,0) ;
        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) ;
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),1000,pindent) ;
```

And this is the service code snippet:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId) ;
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance() ;
        String cdate, ctime ;
        SimpleDateFormat sf=new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yyyy") ;
        SimpleDateFormat sd=new SimpleDateFormat("H:m") ;   
        cdate=sf.format(cal.getTime()) ;
        ctime=sd.format(cal.getTime()) ;
        Bundle b ;
        b=intent.getExtras() ;
        String m1=b.getString("date") ;
        String m2=b.getString("time") ;
        String m3=b.getString("num")  ;
        String m4=b.getString("message") ;
        if(m1.equals(cdate) && m2.equals(ctime) && f!=1)
        {   SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault() ;
        sms.sendTextMessage(m3,null,m4,null,null) ;
            Toast.makeText(this,"Message sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;
            //super.onDestroy();
            m2="done" ;
        }
        else
            {
                q=1 ;
                //f=2 ;
            }
        return 0 ;

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ActivityManager ama=(ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) ;
      }
```

I cannot stop the service...it keeps on sending SMSs from the given time..Any ideas please??I m new to android development....Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `stopself` from the `Service` after work of `Service` is done:

```
sms.sendTextMessage(m3,null,m4,null,null) ;
stopself();
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf%28%29) for more details.

Comment: this didnt work....it sends the message and then the toast "Service Stopped" appears and again the messages are sent repeatedly....any ideas??

Comment: This is because you have set alarm to repeating. Do not use setRepeating.

Comment: Accept this as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to stop your service which is running in background.
To stop the running background service

```
Intent svc = new Intent(MainActivity.this , BackGroundActivity.class);
stopService(svc);
```

Here BackGroundActivity is the activity running in the background.
MainActivity is the activity from where BackGroungActivity is running. 
Hope this helps..!!

Comment: Sorry i couldnt understand your answer.Just to be clear i have the first code as SecondActivity.java and the service(second snippet)as SmsSrevice.java and should I add the code you mentioned in the second snippet after the SMS part?